# Save httppostedfilebase as image in SQL

Tags: httppostedfilebase

I have a situation where I am getting an image as httppostedfilebase type in my MVC code. I have a corresponding Image type column in my SQL db.

I need to know how do I convert/Save this httppostedfilebase type as image in my DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a function to convert HttpPostedFileBase object to file

```
public byte[] ConvertToByte(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        byte[] imageByte = null;
        BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
        imageByte = rdr.ReadBytes((int)file.ContentLength);
        return imageByte;
    }
```

Code like this in Your Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(AdminDetailsViewModel viewmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ImageData"];
        viewmodel.Image = ConvertToByte(file);
        db.YourDbContextSet.Add(viewmodel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help